# How to get a list of domains blocked by my ISP/MikroTik router?

Tags: windows, ip, blocking, nslookup

As imposed by my government, my ISP blocks some sites, like Facebook and YouTube.

The ISP's MikroTik device redirects the blocked websites to a local IP address (192.168.222.66), which says that the site is blocked.

How can I get a list of all sites that are blocked? (I'm not trying to access the blocked sites; I know how to access them, but I just want to get a list.)

I tried some `nslookup` commands to get the domains given the local IP address, but to no avail.

Comment: Use a proxy or get a new ISP

Comment: Try using tracert, it might go to the site and give you the IP before the redirect. Although if it's at the ISP level then I doubt it will get to the site.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you trying to find all of the web sites that are redirected to 192.168.222.66 or are you trying to access all the web sites that are redirected to 192.168.222.66?

Comment: Are you sure it's an ISP, and not some company restriction, or something in your modem/router? If you're sure, then what is showing on 192.168.222.66? (I find it odd that an IP address in [the private range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) is used.)

Comment: @joeqwerty
I'm not trying to access these sites i know how to access them i just want to get a list of blocked sites

Comment: @Arjan
The restriction is imposed by the ministry of communications in my country but so they use MIKROTIK to redirect the sites to 192.168.222.66 which has i page that says that this site is blocked

Comment: :-( If the device that shows the 192.168.222.66 page is actually in your home, then I wonder if that very same device has some blacklist. Like [someone describes](http://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=58341) *"We have a central server that creates a MikroTik .rsc script every night that creates a blacklist address-list [...]. A script on the MikroTik then does a "fetch" of this script on a nightly basis and runs it. Corresponding firewall rules then block connections from this address-list."*

Comment: Just to be sure: do you have any access to some configuration of that MikroTik device? And any model number?

Comment: @Arjan NO i don't have access to the mikrotik device it is setup on the office of the wifi network that i get internet from.

Comment: Okay... I wonder if the device is indeed downloading such "rsc" files, and if anyone has already figured out the URL for your specific provider. If you know who's the provider, does a (Google) search for their name along with "rsc" give any hits?

Comment: @Arjan the name of my isp is "EarthLink Ltd. Communications&Internet Services"

Answer (score 1):

Using a proxy server is always a good and would most likely resolve your issue.  Another potential option is to change your DNS servers to 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4 (Google Public DNS) and see if that works.  If neither of those options work, most likely due to packet inspection from the provider, using a Encrypted VPN should work.

Comment: (I thought you were right, but the question was actually a bit different and has meanwhile been clarified.)

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is just hitting the secured version of the site.

https://facebook.com or https://youtube.com

Most filters only block based on domain names and since the domain name is going over ssl the ISP's filter will only see an IP address pass through the system.

You can also use something like ultrasurf if you want to go the proxy/vpn route.

Comment: Really? The "domain name goes over SSL"? Not in my experience. I have a DNS filter set up on our network; it does *not* work to bypass a DNS filter by prefixing `https://` to it. However, a VPN/Proxy could work.

Comment: Indeed, it won't stop DNS filtering, but I didn't even know such is used, as DNS filtering is easily circumvented using a HOSTS file? Once the IP address is known, the host name is sent to the web server over SSL and can no longer be sniffed.